# When changing tab selections, child panels are not redrawn unless widnow screen is minimized, maximized or restored

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tabcontrol

I'm having an issue with a Windows Forms project. I change tabs but the change does not reflect unless I maximize,minimize,or restore the entire window. After that the newly selected tab will show it's child contents.

I've narrowed the issue down to my trying to programmatic create and name a datagridview

I can do this:

```
            logs_datagrid.Name = "datagrid_logs";
            logs_datagrid.AutoSize = true;
            logs_datagrid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            logs_datagrid.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F);
            logs_datagrid.DataSource = dt_logs_google;
            logs_datagrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            logs_datagrid.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            logs_datagrid.BringToFront(); 

            splitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Add(logs_datagrid);
```

but as soon as I try to programatically apply edits to the datagridview columns the issue occurs. Just uncommenting the top line here will cause the error.

```
            DataGridViewColumn dvg_col_1 = logs_datagrid.Columns[0];
           // DataGridViewColumn dgv_col_2 = logs_datagrid.Columns[1];
           // DataGridViewColumn dgv_col_3 = logs_datagrid.Columns[3];

            //dgv_col_1.ReadOnly = true;
           // dgv_col_1.MinimumWidth = 200;
            //dgv_col_2.ReadOnly = true;
            //dgv_col_2.MinimumWidth = 200;
            //dgv_col_3.ReadOnly = true;
            //dgv_col_3.MinimumWidth = 200;
           // dgv_col_3.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

[edit] Thank you for the help!

Comment: Databinding won't occur if the control is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `Update();`.

(Didn't check this case, but I've seen `Update();` work, when `Invalidate();` didn't.)

Comment: Yes, `Update()` forces the control to redraw its invalidated regions. Invalidate just indicates that a region should be updated the next time the control is redrawn. The `Refresh` method combines these, invalidating the entire control and then updating (redrawing) it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Invalidate() of your control

http://windowsclient.net/articles/windowsformspainting.aspx